# Is there any way to change material-ui data-grid default text

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UIs Data-Grid in my project(@mui/x-data-grid),
and I have wondered if it is possible to change the default text of some of the data grid`s elements.
for example:
[image]

I am using the data grid with RTL support, which makes the "Rows per page" look awkward, and I want to change it to my native language, is it possible?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do that by changing the CSS, just check the API Docs for Grid and check for the relevant css class for which you want to change the styling.

Comment: this is not advisable because you'd have to 'setInnerHtml' which can be dangerous no? Docs give entry into the component via props.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: this is a known issue [here](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/1854), with solution below:

```
<DataGrid
  componentsProps={{
    pagination: {
      labelRowsPerPage: t('key.rowPerPageTranslation')
    }
  }}
/>
```

For anyone else visiting this looking to change ALL text locale on the DataGrid table I explain in more detail below. I changed the Density text to 'Hello World' below with the following code:

```
<DataGrid
        getRowId={(row) => row.id} 
        rows={[...tableRow]}
        columns={columns}
        pageSize={+pageSize}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[5,10,15,20]}
        checkboxSelection
        onPageSizeChange={(newPage) => setPageSize(+newPage)}
        onRowDoubleClick={displayData}
        pagination
        components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
        localeText={{
          toolbarDensity:'Hello World'
        }} ...
```

[image]

you can access the `localeTextConstants` file and match it with the correct prop [here](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/HEAD/packages/grid/x-data-grid/src/constants/localeTextConstants.ts)

To do so, match the correct key to the text (checkout the github repo).
For a more in-depth explanation on how I found it, read below.

By searching through the typescript files you can see all props you can pass. For instance, you'll see the **DataGridComponent** takes in a DataGrid Props within the `DataGrid.d.ts` file:

```
interface DataGridComponent {
    <R extends GridValidRowModel = any>(props: DataGridProps<R> & React.RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>): JSX.Element;
    propTypes?: any;
}
```

Note the interface for the DataGridProps

```
export declare type DataGridProps<R extends GridValidRowModel = any> = Omit<Partial<DataGridPropsWithDefaultValues> & DataGridPropsWithComplexDefaultValueBeforeProcessing & DataGridPropsWithoutDefaultValue<R>, DataGridForcedPropsKey> & {
    pagination?: true;
};
```

**DataGridPropsWithComplexDefaultValueBeforeProcessing** contains a  **GridLocaleText** type for the property `localeText`.

```
export interface DataGridPropsWithComplexDefaultValueAfterProcessing {
    components: GridSlotsComponent;
    localeText: GridLocaleText;
}

export interface GridLocaleText {
    noRowsLabel: string;
    noResultsOverlayLabel: string;
    errorOverlayDefaultLabel: string;
    toolbarDensity: React.ReactNode;
    toolbarDensityLabel: string;
    toolbarDensityCompact: string;
    toolbarDensityStandard: string;
    toolbarDensityComfortable: string;
    toolbarColumns: React.ReactNode;
    toolbarColumnsLabel: string;
    toolbarFilters: React.ReactNode;
    toolbarFiltersLabel: string;
    toolbarFiltersTooltipHide: React.ReactNode;
    toolbarFiltersTooltipShow: React.ReactNode;
    toolbarFiltersTooltipActive: (count: number) => React.ReactNode;
    toolbarQuickFilterPlaceholder: string;
    toolbarQuickFilterLabel: string;
    toolbarQuickFilterDeleteIconLabel: string;
    toolbarExport: React.ReactNode;
    toolbarExportLabel: string;
    toolbarExportCSV: React.ReactNode;
    toolbarExportPrint: React.ReactNode;
    toolbarExportExcel: string;
    columnsPanelTextFieldLabel: string;
    columnsPanelTextFieldPlaceholder: string;
    columnsPanelDragIconLabel: string;
    columnsPanelShowAllButton: React.ReactNode;
    columnsPanelHideAllButton: React.ReactNode;
    filterPanelAddFilter: React.ReactNode;
    filterPanelDeleteIconLabel: string;
    filterPanelLinkOperator: string;
    filterPanelOperators: React.ReactNode;
    filterPanelOperatorAnd: React.ReactNode;
    filterPanelOperatorOr: React.ReactNode;
    filterPanelColumns: React.ReactNode;
    filterPanelInputLabel: string;
    filterPanelInputPlaceholder: string;
    filterOperatorContains: string;
    filterOperatorEquals: string;
    filterOperatorStartsWith: string;
    filterOperatorEndsWith: string;
    filterOperatorIs: string;
    filterOperatorNot: string;
    filterOperatorAfter: string;
    filterOperatorOnOrAfter: string;
    filterOperatorBefore: string;
    filterOperatorOnOrBefore: string;
    filterOperatorIsEmpty: string;
    filterOperatorIsNotEmpty: string;
    filterOperatorIsAnyOf: string;
    filterValueAny: string;
    filterValueTrue: string;
    filterValueFalse: string;
    columnMenuLabel: string;
    columnMenuShowColumns: React.ReactNode;
    columnMenuFilter: React.ReactNode;
    columnMenuHideColumn: React.ReactNode;
    columnMenuUnsort: React.ReactNode;
    columnMenuSortAsc: React.ReactNode;
    columnMenuSortDesc: React.ReactNode;
    columnHeaderFiltersTooltipActive: (count: number) => React.ReactNode;
    columnHeaderFiltersLabel: string;
    columnHeaderSortIconLabel: string;
    footerRowSelected: (count: number) => React.ReactNode;
    footerTotalRows: React.ReactNode;
    footerTotalVisibleRows: (visibleCount: number, totalCount: number) => React.ReactNode;
    checkboxSelectionHeaderName: string;
    checkboxSelectionSelectAllRows: string;
    checkboxSelectionUnselectAllRows: string;
    checkboxSelectionSelectRow: string;
    checkboxSelectionUnselectRow: string;
    booleanCellTrueLabel: string;
    booleanCellFalseLabel: string;
    actionsCellMore: string;
    pinToLeft: string;
    pinToRight: string;
    unpin: string;
    treeDataGroupingHeaderName: string;
    treeDataExpand: string;
    treeDataCollapse: string;
    groupingColumnHeaderName: string;
    groupColumn: (name: string) => string;
    unGroupColumn: (name: string) => string;
    detailPanelToggle: string;
    expandDetailPanel: string;
    collapseDetailPanel: string;
    rowReorderingHeaderName: string;
    aggregationMenuItemHeader: string;
    aggregationFunctionLabelSum: string;
    aggregationFunctionLabelAvg: string;
    aggregationFunctionLabelMin: string;
    aggregationFunctionLabelMax: string;
    aggregationFunctionLabelSize: string;
    MuiTablePagination: Omit<ComponentsPropsList['MuiTablePagination'], 'page' | 'count' | 'onChangePage' | 'rowsPerPage' | 'onPageChange'>;
}
```